# Spring+EhCache refresh cache list

Tags: java, spring, caching, annotations, ehcache

I'm new with EhCache, so maybe my question is silly, but anyway:
I'm using EhCache with Spring. And have this in my DAO:

```
@Cacheable(value="product", key="#id")
public Product getProductById(Integer id) {//some code;}

@Cacheable(value="productList")
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {//some code;}
```

I want to update my productList cache when I delete or update some product. Can I do smthg like this in my code to resolve this issue (in this example productList and product caches both deleted):

```
@Caching(evict={@CacheEvict(value="productList", allEntries=true), @CacheEvict(value="product", key="#id")})
public boolean deleteProductById(Integer id) { //some code;}
```

Maybe, there is some way to do this without annotation. Be glad for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: It looks correct. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I tried it. This code just delete my product and productList cache. But I don't want to delete productList cache. I want find object by some key in productList cache and delete just it, without productList cache delete. Can I do this?

Comment: Have you check out `@CachePut`?

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand how can I use it. I should write smthg like this: @Caching(evict={ @CacheEvict( value = "product", key = "#id")}, put= { @CachePut(value = "productList", key="#id")}) above my delete method? Maybe you have some example? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Try simply using `@Caching{put={@CachePut(value="productList", key="#id"), @CachePut(value="product", key="#id")}` and let me know

Comment: It doesn't work. And if I understand correctly it shouldn't: I store a List<Product> products as one Element object in productList cache with id=0, and when my delete method called: @CachePut looking Element object in my productList cache by key. And if there is a match this annotation just delete my List<Product> products from cache and put Product object (that I try to delete) instead of it. If this annotation doesn't find matching key, It just put new Element object to my productList cache. And productList cache size will be 2, not 1. I can't find any example. Maybe, It is not possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

it works with me in this way

```
@CacheEvict(value="productList", allEntries=true)
public boolean deleteProductById(Integer id) {
    //some code;
}
```